# getting an item that is not in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I am supposed to add items from `list_q2` that are in `list_q2` and present in `dict_q2`, into a dictionary. E.g. `{ "ketchup": 0.95, "oranges":-1, "pear": None }`. The Keys for this dict is the result of dividing `dict_q2` value first item with its second item. In this instance, 950/1000. For items that experience zero divisional error their values would be -1 as seen with orange. However for items present in `list_q2` but not in `dict_q2`, their values in the newly added dictionary would be none as seen in the instance of pear. I am stuck at producing `"pear":None`. In conclusion, to produce the outcomes of -1 or None, exception handling has to be used and I cant use if else statement for this assignment. I hope someone can help me out, thanks!

```
      dict_q2 = {"vinegar": [120.0, 100],"ketchup": [950, 1000],"apples":[850,1100],"oranges": [1050, 0]}

list_q2 = ["ketchup","oranges","pear"]



class noneError(Exception):
def __init__(self, message = "None"):
    self.message = message


def compute_unit_prices(dict_goods, list_goods):
#dict variable with name of good as key and unit prices as values. 
return_dict = {}
all_keys = dict_goods.keys()
#Try block
try:
    for i in range(len(list_goods)):
        goods_name = list_goods[i]
        storage = dict_goods[goods_name]
        results = storage[0] / storage[1]
        return_dict.update({goods_name:results})
        
except noneError as e:
    results = e.message
    return_dict.update({goods_name:results})
# If zeroDivisionError is encountered, this block of code is used
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    results = -1
    return_dict.update({goods_name:results})
# This block of code works if errors other than the above two occurs
except:
    return_dict = {}
finally:
    print(return_dict)
```

In the main method I will call this function

```
compute_unit_prices(dict_q2, list_q2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
storage = dict_goods[goods_name]
```

use

```
storage = dict_goods.get(goods_name, None)
```

with second argument being your fail-safe option.

Comment: Edited, my bad.